# Adding a field to mongoose find query result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this employee schema in mongoose :

```
employeesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    title: String,
    managerId: {
        type:Number,
        required: false
    },
    managerName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    phone: String,
    mobilePhone: String,
    email: String,
    picture: String,
});
```

And I have my function to find employee :

```
module.exports.getEmployeeById = function(id, callback){

Employee.find({ {id: id} }, callback);
```

}

but I want to have a one more field in result beside all the fields of my Schema, a field that is an array for the employees who has managerId:id ( the employees below this employee).

Thanks

Comment: I don't feel this provides enough detail to merit a whole answer, but what you're looking for is called Populate (like joins with SQL): http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: I don't want to populate my model or db I want to add a field in the query json response

Comment: @YassineBHS what is wrong with a simple loop assuming you don't want to use `populate` as mentioned ?

Comment: if I use populate I have to change my Schema which is not what I want, I want to be able to get json response like this : https://employee-directory-services.herokuapp.com/employees/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** pipeline operator to dso a "self-join" and get the employees with this `id` as their manager (in an array named `subordinates`) as follows:

```
module.exports.getEmployeeById = function(id, callback){

    Employee.aggregate([
        { "$match": { id: id } },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "employees",
                "localField": "id",
                "foreignField": "managerId",
                "as": "subordinates"
            }
        }
    ]).exec(callback);

}
```

Comment: this isn't working for me, I get an empty array in the json response

Comment: Have you tried running it with just the `$match` pipeline as a way of debugging the operation? It could be that it didn't find a match hence the empty array. If that's the case then you can also debug the pipeline by hardcoding an `id` value for an existing document or just run the pipeline with just the `$lookup` step.

Comment: when I use Employee.find( {id: id} , callback); It works
but when I use the aggregate with $match (with or without $lookup) It doesn't work and I get a empty array

Comment: but when I did like you said and passed 1 as id to the function it worked, but how can I pass it in variable ??

Comment: Perhaps you need to parse the id variable first if it's coming from a `req` object, for example `{ "$match": { id: parseint(id) } },`

Comment: Yes it worked, Thank you.. but the thing is this aggregate function return an array I want just one element not an array because that's how I read it in react native.
I will check your answer btw